# Realm DB how to get query output object as unmanaged?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to query my Realm DB such that the output will give an unmanaged object and for that, I changed my `RealmList` type of object to `List`.

Now the thing is in addchangeListener I am getting my output object(`stories`) value as `managed`. But the type of `stories` is `List`. So why my `stories` object is becoming `managed` where it should act as an `unmanaged` object.

```
List<story> stories = realm.where(story.class).findAllAsync();
stories.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<story>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<story> storydata) {
                if (storydata.size() != 0) {
                    madapter = new StoriesAdapter(stories, getBaseContext(), MR);
                    mrecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                    mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext()));
                    mrecyclerview.setAdapter(madapter);
                }
            }
        });
```

**StoriesAdapter**

```
class StoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

       List<story> storyList;

       StoriesAdapter(List<story> storyList) {
           this.storyList = storyList;
       }
 }
```

I am saying my `List` is `managed` because when i am trying to write below code I am getting `Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.`

```
madapter.storyList.get(3).setTitle("Wonderland"); // where storyList is List which i am pointing to `stories`.
```

Comment: does the listener works 100% during testing?

Comment: yes, but why are you asking ??

Comment: who said it was managed, its still unmanaged.

Comment: It is managed because now when I am trying to change `List` inside my `madapter` then I am getting `Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.` Which means my list which I initialised in my adapter method is `managed`.

Comment: why are you even passing realm objects like that, memory problems will creep up on you. Always query the object in separate classes.

Comment: I have updated my post. Also, `why should I query in different classes what issues will I face`, Can you please elaborate ??

Comment: @Remario elaborate what you mean? elements in RealmResults are obtained lazily, so it shouldn't cause any "memory problems to creep up on you"? What memory problems?

Comment: check posted answer

Answer (score 1):

> `List<story> stories = realm.where(story.class).findAllAsync();`

Because specifying the type `List<story>` just means you'll see the returned list as a `List<story>`, but technically it's still a `RealmResults<story>`.

> `stories.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<story>>() {`

This line underneath shouldn't even compile.

---

Stories should be stored in a `field`.

```
private RealmResults<story> stories;

public void ...() {
    stories = ...
    stories.addChangeListener(...
```

---

Anyways, so you are working with RealmResults, which means that in

```
class StoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   List<story> storyList;
```

This `storyList` you provided is a `RealmResults<story>`, so calling `storyList.get(...)` will return managed RealmObjects.

---

Managed RealmObjects are "temporarily immutable", meaning they can only be modified in a transaction. It is also generally not recommended to run write transactions on the UI thread.

---

The simplest way would be to use [`realm-android-adapters`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters).

```
class StoriesAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<story, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   StoriesAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<story> stories) {
       super(stories, true, true);
   }
}
```

And when you want to modify an object, you do

```
story item = getData().get(3);
final String id = item.getId();
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        story changedItem = realm.where(story.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
        changedItem.setTitle("Wonderland");
    }
});
```

And then Realm will handle automatically updating the RealmResults, the `story` object, and the RecyclerView.

---

---

**EDIT:** If you intend to use unmanaged objects, then you could use `realm.copyFromRealm(results)`, except that does the read on the UI thread.

You could create a background looper thread and obtain the results from there, but managing that could be tricky. Luckily for you, there's a library I made called [**Monarchy**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy) which lets you do exactly that.

See the [**relevant sample code for how you'd use it**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/blob/72dd547c82acc4701c7cf948dd2bbbdc62fd62e0/monarchy-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchyexample/features/copied/CopiedFragment.java).

Comment: Agreed, how was it possible to cast though?

Comment: Because `RealmResults<T> implements OrderedRealmCollection<T>`, and `OrderedRealmCollection<T> extends List<T>`. There was no actual "casting" involved. As for the `addChangeListener`, as I said, that should not compile :D

Comment: Exactly i am surprised, is that a version thing?

Comment: No, I think the question is just incorrect somehow.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks but actually currently I want to work with unmanaged objects only, can you tell me how can I get an unmanaged object in the output of a query ??

Answer (score 0):

The stories is implicitly Managed, the reason is that `RealmResults` extends the list interface abstractly. Thats why the casting is possible, underneath the same mechanisms for a `RealmResults` still takes precedence. Also, you should only pass `RealmResults` instance to an Adapter directly, if you register a `RealmChangeListener` on it, which will call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Otherwise, writes will update the RealmResults content, and your adapter will be desynchronized.

Realm is not like SQLite or Core Data. If you’re using Realm, take advantage of live objects. Don’t implement any refreshing logic or requerying. Always allow the current class to own its own instance of a realm query.

This fact is true,Realm objects and any child objects are NOT thread-safe. They’re confined to a single thread to ensure that atomic rights are maintained. There is an internal list where every single thread has its own unique Realm instance. If you want to pass objects between a thread–for example, if you create a dog object on the main thread, pass it to the background thread, and then try and access a property–it will trigger an exception straight away.

Also you are using asynchronous query,  which puts it on a worker thread.

Comment: In order to provide the consistency and safety Realm guarantees, a simple constraint is imposed: all Realms, objects, results, and lists are confined to the thread on which they created.

Comment: Even though the adaptor uses the main thread in your example, your passing a memory reference to the adaptor.

Comment: It’s important to understand that thread-confinement isn’t a temporary limitation based on Realm’s internals, or an artificial constraint, but rather a crucial part of the design that makes it easier to write correct code.

Comment: To have isolation (the ‘I’ in ACID), changes in different transactions aren’t reflected in other transactions until those transactions advance to the latest version. The key term here is ISOLATION.

Comment: Sorry, but why I am getting the error, can you please explain ??

Comment: YOU ARE GETTING THIS ERROR BECAUSE STORIES IS ACTUALLY A REALM RESULT LIST, WHICH IS MANAGED, AND BECAUSE ITS MANAGED ANY WRITES NEEDS TO BE ESCAPSULATE IN A COMMIT TRANSACTION.